# How to build relationships many-to-many?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to implement the sql-query using Sequelize, but it doesn't work. Here is the source data.

**There are tables(columns):**

```
Dog: id
TelSprav: id, numtel (number directory)
Tel: id, id_tel, id_dog
Tex: id, id_tel
```

**SQL-Query:**

```
SELECT d.dogovor, t.address, tx.ats
    
FROM dog d
    left join tel t on d.id = t.id_dog
    left join tex tx on t.id_tel = tx.id_tel
```

**Sequelize:**

```
const data = await Dog.findAll({
    attributes: ['dogovor'],
    include: [
        { model: Tel,
          include: [{model: Tex, attributes: ['ats'], required: false}],
          attributes: ['address'],
          required: false }
    ]
})
```

**Relationship table:**

```
"TelSprav" & "Tel": One-to-Many
"Tel" & "Tex": Many-to-Many.
```

**I created Relationships:**

```
Tel.belongsToMany(Tex, {through: TelSprav, foreignKey: 'id_tel'})
Tex.belongsToMany(Tel, {through: TelSprav, foreignKey: 'id_tel'})
```

**Result console...**

```
SELECT...
FROM "dog" AS dog 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tel ON dog.id = tel.id_dog 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        telSprav INNER JOIN tex ON tex.id = telSprav.id_tel
    ) ON tel.id = telSprav.id_tel
```

**...out error:** "column telSprav.id_tel does not exist"

---

Please, tell me, how to create a model for the sql-query?
Аnd why is this happening **tex.id = telSprav.id_tel**, while it should be the other way around?

Comment: I think `Tex.belongsToMany(Tel, {through: TelSprav, foreignKey: 'id_tel'})` should be `Tex.belongsToMany(Tel, {through: TelSprav, foreignKey: 'id_tex'})` 
and then `telSprav INNER JOIN tex ON tex.id = telSprav.id_tel` can be `telSprav INNER JOIN tex ON tex.id = telSprav.id_tex`

Comment: No. `TelSprav.id = Tel.id_tel, TelSprav.id = Tex.id_tel.` Another fields (id_tex) not need.
The main problem is why the fields are swapped:
`tex.id = telSprav.id_tel`
while it should be the other way around:
`tex.id_tel = telSprav.id